# Get Multiple Rows on SQLite in Flutter

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, dart, async-await

I keep only the "`productID`" information of the products added to the favorites in the "`favorite`" table in the database. I had no problem adding this information to the table. (`product` table and `favorite` table are separate.) But when I wanted to list all favorite products in the table, I found the codes that allowed me to query one by one. What I need is a function that can give the `List<int> productIDs` as parameter and return favorite products as `List<Map<String, dynamic>>>` . I looked almost everywhere but could not find it.
The function I use to fetch favorite product IDs stored in the `favorite` table:

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> favProds() async{
    List<int> IDs = new List<int>();
    var db = await _getDatabase();
    var result = await db.query(_favTable, orderBy: '$_columnProdID DESC');
    for(Map incomingMap in result){
      IDs.add(incomingMap['prodID']);
    }
    return _getFavProdsWithIDList(IDs);
  }
```

This is my function that takes the ID List as a parameter and returns a list containing favorite products as maps:

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> _getFavProdsWithIDList(List<int> IDs) async{
    var db = await _getDatabase();
    var result = await db.query("$_prodTable", where: '$_columnProdID = ?', whereArgs: IDs);
    return result;
  }
```

Here is the error I get when I use them:

```
Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(Cannot bind argument at index 8 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1 parameters.) sql 'SELECT * FROM urun WHERE urunID = ?' args [230, 180, 179, 20, 19, 18, 17, 2]}
```

From this error, we see that adding products to the `favorite` table is successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wan select records where id in list of ids you should use query like

```
SELECT * FROM urun WHERE urunID IN (1, 2, 3);
```

You have two options.

1. Provide same number of placeholders as list length

```
final placeholders = List.generate(5,(_) => "?").join(",");
var result = await db.query("$_prodTable", where: '$_columnProdID IN ($placeholders)', whereArgs: IDs);
```

2. Since ids is integers just

```
var result = await db.query("$_prodTable", where: '$_columnProdID IN (${IDs.join(",")})');
```